# Django - conditional foreign key

Tags: python, django, orm

I have the following 4 models in my program - User, Brand, Agency and Creator.

User is a superset of Brand, Agency and Creator.

A user can be a brand, agency or creator. They cannot take on more than one role. Their role is defined by the `accountType` property. If they are unset (i.e. 0) then no formal connection exists.

How do I express this in my model?

User model

```
class User(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid4, editable=False)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, null=True, default=None)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, default=None)
    ACCOUNT_CHOICE_UNSET = 0
    ACCOUNT_CHOICE_BRAND = 1
    ACCOUNT_CHOICE_CREATOR = 2
    ACCOUNT_CHOICE_AGENCY = 3
    ACCOUNT_CHOICES = (
        (ACCOUNT_CHOICE_UNSET, 'Unset'),
        (ACCOUNT_CHOICE_BRAND, 'Brand'),
        (ACCOUNT_CHOICE_CREATOR, 'Creator'),
        (ACCOUNT_CHOICE_AGENCY, 'Agency'),
    )
    account_id = models.ForeignKey(Brand)
    account_type = models.IntegerField(choices=ACCOUNT_CHOICES, default=ACCOUNT_CHOICE_UNSET)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Users"

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % self.email
```

Brand model

```
class Brand(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid4, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, default=None)
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, default=None)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, null=True, default=None)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, default=None)
    website = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, default=None)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Brands"

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % self.brand
```

Creator model

```
class Creator(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid4, editable=False)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, default=None)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, default=None)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, null=True, default=None)
    youtube_channel_username = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, default=None)
    youtube_channel_url = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, default=None)
    youtube_channel_title = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, default=None)
    youtube_channel_description = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, default=None)
    photo = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, default=None)
    youtube_channel_start_date = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, default=None)
    keywords = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, default=None)
    no_of_subscribers = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    no_of_videos = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    no_of_views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    no_of_likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    no_of_dislikes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, default=None)
    avg_views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    GENDER_CHOICE_UNSET = 0
    GENDER_CHOICE_MALE = 1
    GENDER_CHOICE_FEMALE = 2
    GENDER_CHOICES = (
        (GENDER_CHOICE_UNSET, 'Unset'),
        (GENDER_CHOICE_MALE, 'Male'),
        (GENDER_CHOICE_FEMALE, 'Female'),
    )
    gender = models.IntegerField(choices=GENDER_CHOICES, default=GENDER_CHOICE_UNSET)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Creators"

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s %s" % (self.first_name,self.last_name)
```

Agency model

```
class Agency(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid4, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, default=None)
    agency = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, default=None)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, null=True, default=None)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, default=None)
    website = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, default=None)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Agencies"

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % self.agency
```

Update:

So I've whittled it down to this bit here in the model:

```
ACCOUNT_CHOICE_UNSET = 0
ACCOUNT_CHOICE_BRAND = 1
ACCOUNT_CHOICE_CREATOR = 2
ACCOUNT_CHOICE_AGENCY = 3
ACCOUNT_CHOICES = (
    (ACCOUNT_CHOICE_UNSET, 'Unset'),
    (ACCOUNT_CHOICE_BRAND, 'Brand'),
    (ACCOUNT_CHOICE_CREATOR, 'Creator'),
    (ACCOUNT_CHOICE_AGENCY, 'Agency'),
)
account_type = models.IntegerField(choices=ACCOUNT_CHOICES, default=ACCOUNT_CHOICE_UNSET)
limit = models.Q(app_label='api', model='Brand') | \
        models.Q(app_label='api', model='Creator') | \
        models.Q(app_label='api', model='Agency')
content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, limit_choices_to=get_content_type_choices(), related_name='user_content_type')
content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'email')
```

- If account_type = 1 then link to brand model
- If account_type = 2 then link to creator model
- If account_type = 3 then link to agency model

How do I accomplish this? Getting this error:

```
  File "/Users/projects/adsoma-api/api/models.py", line 7, in <module>
    class User(models.Model):
  File "/Users/projects/adsoma-api/api/models.py", line 28, in User
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, limit_choices_to=get_content_type_choices(), related_name='user_content_type')
NameError: name 'get_content_type_choices' is not defined
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried exploring Django's `GenericForeignKey` field?

```
class User(models.Model):
    ...
    limit = models.Q(app_label='your_app_label', model='brand') | 
            models.Q(app_label='your_app_label', model='creator') | 
            models.Q(app_label='your_app_label', model='agency')
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, limit_choices_to=limit, related_name='user_content_type')
    object_id = models.UUIDField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

You can access the User's brand/creator/agency by using the following notation:

`User.objects.get(pk=1).content_object`

This will be an instance of `Brand`/`Creator`/`Agency` as per the `content_type`.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#django.contrib.contenttypes.fields.GenericForeignKey

#### Update based on your comment

#### Re 1: Using email:

```
class User(models.Model):
    ...
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    limit = models.Q(app_label='your_app_label', model='brand') | 
            models.Q(app_label='your_app_label', model='creator') | 
            models.Q(app_label='your_app_label', model='agency')
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, limit_choices_to=get_content_type_choices, related_name='user_content_type')
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'email')
```

*Note: Email can not be a nullable field anywhere if you follow this approach! Also this approach seems hacky/wrong since the `email` field is now declared in multiple places; and the value can change if you re-assign the content objects. It is much cleaner to link the `GenericForeignKey` using the discrete `UUIDField` on each of the other three models*

#### Re 2: Using `account_type` field:

`ContentType` is expected to be a reference to a Django Model; therefore it requires choices that are Models and not integers.
The function of `limit_choices_to` is to perform a filtering such that all possible models are not surfaced as potential `GenericForeignKey`

```
class ContentType(models.Model):
    app_label = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    model = models.CharField(_('python model class name'), max_length=100)
    objects = ContentTypeManager()
```

However, `limit_choices_to` does accept callables; so you can write a helper method that translates your `account_type` to the correct `Model`

I am not clear about how this transaltion should work; so I leave that to you.

Comment: Thanks, the primary key on the User's brand/creator/agency is email. How do I express this? Also is it possible to tie this implementation to the account_type field, which is 0,1,2 and corresponds to a particular user?

Comment: This is what I've done: https://pastebin.com/Gc4vHshM. But it's still not working... `no such column: api_user.content_type_id`.

Comment: Basically 1 = Brand, 2 = Creator, 3 = Agency

Comment: Update your question with the full stack trace

Comment: `get_content_type_choices` is a function I left for you to define to achieve #2: mapping the choices to `account_type`. Revert that code to `get_content_type_choices=limit` to get everything but #2 working

Comment: So I'm not sure if the instance of the object is available for you to look at it's account type. In your implementation, `account_type` points to the field that you've defined, not the value of an instance of a user. Ideally, I'd change `account _type` to a property, or use a post save signal to set it appropriately

Comment: I'm not really sure how to do this... can you please help?

Comment: What's the purpose for `account_type` -> is it for use in python on in SQL?

Comment: During signup, its used to identify whether or not the user is a brand, account or creator

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170414/discussion-between-rtindru-and-methuselah).

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solve it, override the `save` method check your condition
tested on Django 3.2

```
CUSTOMER = [
    ('customer', 'customer'),
    ('supplier', 'supplier'),
]


class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=False, blank=False)

    user_type = models.CharField(max_length=32, choices=CUSTOMER)


class SupplierOrder(models.Model):
    price = models.FloatField(default=0)
    supplier = models.ForeignKey(Customer, related_name='supplier', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        supplier = get_object_or_404(Customer, id=self.supplier.id)
        if supplier.user_type != 'supplier':
            raise ValueError('selected user must be supplier')
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```